# Should I use a macros in this case? Or ...

Tags: macros, elixir, phoenix-framework

Say, I have this part of a config in Phoenix/Elixir:

```
use Mix.Config

config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  var1: 111,
  var2: 222,
  var3_depends_on_var2: ???? # var2 + 666
```

I want the value of "var3_depends_on_var2" to depend on "var2", at the same time I don't want to explicitly copy-paste it. If I can't refer to it, I believe I should use a macros instead. Is it so? If yes, how? Is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these lines are nothing but the call to [`Mix.config/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/master/Mix.Config.html#config/3) and everthing happened in the last parameter, that is a `Keyword` list, one can’t simply refer one `Keyword` value from another during declaration.

What you could use is just preliminary `var` declaration:

```
use Mix.Config
var = 222

config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  var1: 111,
  var2: var,
  var3_depends_on_var2: var + 666
```

Comment: You can’t, due to the reason I put in the first sentence. As by Chris McCord: the first rule of using macros is you should not use macros. I understand your willingness to use them just because now you can, but this is a wrong way. Everything that can be done without macros, should be done without them.

Comment: не ну че ты блин в самом деле?

Comment: Использование макросов просто «потому что могу» — очень плохая практика. Почитайте Metaprogramming Elixir Криса, серьезно.

Comment: I mean, technically you *can* write a macro that will expand to this code or something. But you're just better off writing it this way instead of having low-value indirection

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an Elixir script file, you can just use normal variables:

```
use Mix.Config

var2 = 222

config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  var1: 111,
  var2: var2,
  var3_depends_on_var2: var2 + 666
```

I can't think of any not super complicated way to do this with macros.

Comment: There is no even super complicated way to do this with macros because `var2` happen to appear inside the same term declaration as `var3`. There is no access to it via `Keyword` at this very moment due to `Keyword` itself is not yet defined.

Comment: My super complicated method was to rewrite `myconfig :foo, Bar, a: b, c: d, e: f` to `a = b; c = d; e = f; config :foo, Bar, a: a, c: c, e: e` (where `b`, `d`, and `f` are expressions). I think that would work.